# WinHttpRequest in Inno Setup doesn't send credentials with Authenticate header

Tags: inno-setup, winhttprequest

Based on some SO question I saw earlier, I'm using `WinHttpRequest` inside of Inno Setup to make a `GET` request to a web server (`localhost:8000` right now). Minimal code below, the request is to the built-in Django debug server (`python manage.py runserver`).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
    WinHttpReq: Variant;
    url: string;
    HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER: integer;
begin
    url := 'http://localhost:8000/odbc/test/';
    HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER := 0;

    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', url, false);
    WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    WinHttpReq.SetCredentials('username','password',HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);
    WinHttpReq.Send();
    MsgBox(WinHttpReq.Status, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    MsgBox(WinHttpReq.ResponseText, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

This gives me a 403, authentication credentials not provided.

On the contrary, this code in the Python requests library works successfully.

```python
>> import requests
>> r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/odbc/test/', auth=('username','password'))
>> r.status_code
200
```

Am I misunderstanding how the `WinHttpRequest` object works? Because Wireshark confirms an `Authorization: Basic *hashstring*` header was sent in the header with the Python requests, but not in the `WinHttpRequest` case. A likely workaround would be to set the header myself for the `WinHttpRequest` object but I'm just curious if I'm doing anything wrong.

Gist with packet captures: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/597468ba76b59dae4a8d7809ee1c6feb

Wireshark screenshots:

[image: WinHttpRequest in Inno Setup Wireshark capture]

[image: Python requests library Wireshark capture]

Comment: Works for me (against Apache server) - 1) Do you have any special characters in the username/password? 2) Can you try to capture the HTTP traffic using e.g. Wireshark, both for the Inno Setup code and the Python code? And post them here? Or at least webserver logs for both.

Comment: Added wireshark capture screenshots. Is there a better format for posting wireshark captures?

Comment: When you stop the capturing, you can save the traffic to a file. Note that that the `WinHttpRequest` sends two HTTP requests. First time, without authentication, and then after receiving 401, it sends second request with authorization. So we need to see both requests, including the responses from the server.

Comment: Added Gist. I do not see where you see two requests from `WinHttpRequest`.

Comment: They are not in your captures, because your server does not send the `WWW-Authenticate` header. But I can see them, when I test your code  against my (Apache) server. If I configure my server to behave as your does (no `WWW-Authenticate` header), I get the same behavior as you (one request only, no `Authenticate` header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is an incompatibility between the `WinHttpRequest` and your "Django debug server".

---

The `WinHttpRequest` sends the `Authenticate` header, only after being challenged by the server with the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

There's no such header in the 403 response from your server. Hence the `WinHttpRequest` does not send the `Authorization` header.

Solutions are:

- Make your server return the `WWW-Authenticate` header (and ideally the 401 status - though this is not required by the `WinHttpRequest`).
- Send the `Authenticate` header explicitly by:

  ```pascal
  WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ???');
  ```